# Insert &trade or &nbsp; using jquery text

Tags: jquery, html, css, insert

I know I can solve this using .html() but i have to use text(). Is there a way by which these values get inserted but on page it shows up as a trademark symbol or empty space ?

Comment: I believe `.text()` wants to treat any string as purely text, without converting any HTML. `&trade;`, etc, decoded would be HTML, if that makes sense.

Comment: Any way I could add some way to escape it? and make it show properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just add the trademark symbol directly into the text string? like this:

HTML:

```
<p></p>
```

JS:

```
$('p').text('™');
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zr8geb36/**

Answer (score 4):

For trade mark:

```
$("#container").text("\u2122");
```

For blank space:

```
$("#container").text("\xA0");
```

It's just replacing **HTML entity** with **HexCode**.

http://jsfiddle.net/cqk2ebqw/

Comment: This one is better because in my case I copy and paste ™ as a text for mail subject line but it's not showing proper in few mail sites like outlook. So better use \u2122 in your string.